# Animate on scroll once

Tags: javascript, scroll

Im using the [fadethis](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-For-Element-Fade-Slide-Effects-As-You-Scroll-FadeThis.html) js plugin and trying to make the animate on scroll only happen once, unsure on where im going wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/robcleaton/pLdwdzpz/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).fadeThis();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple one:

```
$(window).fadeThis({
    reverse:false
});
```

The documents specify this to set up the plugin:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).fadeThis({
    baseName:       "slide-",
    speed:          500, // <a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/">Animation</a> speed in milliseconds.
    easing:         "swing", // Animation easing.
    offset:         0, // <a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Scroll/">Scroll</a> offset, allowing to fire fading a little after or before the element appear.
    reverse:        true, // Make element disappear again when scrolled out, and fade again when scrolled in. 
    distance:       50, // Element distance to its emplacement, before animation.
    scrolledIn:     null, // Function to call when the element come in viewport. 
   scrolledOut:    null // Function to call when the element go out of the viewport. 
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).fadeThis({
        reverse: false;
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y4vx25ow/)**